# Unable to cast results of LINQ query to IEnumerable<MyClassType>

Tags: entity-framework, linq

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`8[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]]]'
>   to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ConsultantManagement.CustomBuffers.CUSTOM_CONSULTANT_LIST]'.

Here's my CUSTOM_CONSULTANT_LIST class:

```
  public class CUSTOM_CONSULTANT_LIST
  {
    public int ID_CONSULTANT { get; set; }
    public string NME_FIRST { get; set; }
    public string NME_LAST { get; set; }
    public string PHN_CELL { get; set; }
    public string NME_PAY_TO { get; set; }
    public string CDE_PAYMENT_METHOD { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IND_ACTIVE { get; set; }
    // Added custom field to contain the MAX Invoice Date for the Consultant...
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LATEST_INVOICE_DATE { get; set; }
  }
```

And here's the code that's failing (First line in the function)...

```
public static IEnumerable<CUSTOM_CONSULTANT_LIST> Get_Consultant_List(ref ConsultantListViewModel vm)
{
  // Retrieve the list of consultants with the latest (MAX) invoice date joined...
  IEnumerable<CUSTOM_CONSULTANT_LIST> query = (IEnumerable<CUSTOM_CONSULTANT_LIST>)(from c in db.CCC_CONSULTANT
                                               join i in db.CCC_INVOICE on c.ID_CONSULTANT equals i.ID_CONSULTANT
               select new
                         {
                           c.ID_CONSULTANT, c.NME_FIRST, c.NME_LAST, c.PHN_CELL, c.NME_PAY_TO, c.CDE_PAYMENT_METHOD, c.IND_ACTIVE, 
                           LATEST_INVOICE_DATE = c.CCC_CONSULTANT_ACTIVITY.Max((a) => a.DTM_ACTIVITY) });

  return query.ToList();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns an enumeration of an anonymous type, as the error message says (this is the "`<>f__AnonymousType18[System.Int32,...`" bit; anonymous types do in a sense have names, but they're composed of Unspeakable Lovecraftian line noise and chthonic jabberwocky):

```
select new
{
    c.ID_CONSULTANT, c.NME_FIRST, ...
```

Try this:

```
select new CUSTOM_CONSULTANT_LIST
{
    ID_CONSULTANT = c.ID_CONSULTANT, 
    NME_FIRST = c.NME_FIRST, 
    //  ... other properties ...
    LATEST_INVOICE_DATE = c.CCC_CONSULTANT_ACTIVITY.Max((a) => a.DTM_ACTIVITY) 
}
```

Comment: Yup - true fact - Cthulu generates the names of anon classes

Comment: Ed,  Thanks so much!